# Eliminating duplicate time

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, analytics

I just want to write a query where there are are two timestamps and the difference between the two is lesser than 15 minutes then keep the one with the minimum and omit the second

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can keep any row where the previous timestamp is `NULL` or greater than 15 minutes.  Use `qualify`:

```
select t.*
from t
where 1=1
qualify lag(timestamp) over (order by timestamp) is null or
        timestamp > timestamp_add(lag(timestamp) over (order by timestamp), interval 15 minute)
```